# Python3 Selenium Button Clicking Issue

Tags: python, selenium

I want to click a button as the following picture shows with Selenium
[image]

I write my code like that:

```
try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/portal/site/16/801']").click()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

**But it always shows error, it cannot locate the element.**
Here is the html code of what I want to click.

```
<a href="/portal/site/16/801" data-blackname="16" title="课程网站">
                                        <img src="/access/img//site/16.png" class="media-icon" onerror="this.src='/resources/images/app-default-icon2.png'">

                                        <h5><i class="icon-ok"></i>课程网站</h5>
```

​

Could somebody help me fix the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you need help then you have to show full page - add url in question (not in comment)

Comment: text "it always shows error" is the most useless information. Always put full error message (full Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Have you tried the Expected Conditions to wait for the element to be clickable?

Comment: @furas Sorry, for the security, I cannot show the full html page code of our school course website. Thank you anyway. I will notice the way the next time I ask a question.

Comment: @supputuri Thank you for your comments. I have successfully entered that by adding a sleep after send(Keys.ENTER). Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As supputuri mentioned, Use explicit waits instead of random sleep. If the lower limit is not enough for the button to be clickable then it will surely make the error random.

The explicit wait is used to tell the Web Driver to wait for certain conditions (Expected Conditions). In this case, the button to be clickable. explicit waits by default check every half a second if the condition is fulfilled or not.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/portal/site/16/801']"))).click()
```

To use this you have to import the followings:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a random sleep after using Selenium to send username, password and ENTER. It works

```
time.sleep(random.randint(3,6))
```